# Laravel Display Images in Shared Hosting

Tags: laravel, shared-hosting

I've developed a site, for a local charity, where their budget is basically zero. I've used Laravel and I managed to source free hosting, for life. They just need to pay for domain name renewal, every year.

LCN Hosting provide the free hosting and 1 year's free domain name, however, it is a shared hosting package, which is less than ideal. I followed the steps, to upload it, by changing the name of the public directory and placing everything else in a second directory, as well as changing the paths in the index.php file and the autoload file and deleting the config.php file.

The site runs, but at times it is a bit sluggish and page load times are higher than is probably acceptable, using a mobile or running it through Google Lighthouse or Screaming Frog.

I work between 2 machines and my desktop has Laragon installed on a D drive, so when I transfer my project to my laptop, I change the paths, in the config file, for all references to a D drive to a C, so for example:

```
'path' => 'B:\\laragon\\www\\projectfinal\\storage\\framework/cache/data',
```

Becomes:

```
'path' => 'C:\\laragon\\www\\projectfinal\\storage\\framework/cache/data',
```

I have no SSH access on the shared hosting, so I can't run any optimisation or cache commands, once its uploaded. Is it possible to spoof the location, to match the folder structure of the shared hosting? I know a virtual or dedicated server would be much better and if it weren't a charity, I would have used one. So any tips would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And this is where virtualisation becomes immensely useful.

Comment: I have had a similar problem, with no access to the server.  
I wrote (behind a secure admin role) some functions that sit on the "admin panel" of the site and execute either artisan or system commands.